# SQL - Select first rows with unique values in two columns from another select

Tags: sql

I have the following query to select the rows that are intresting from a SQL view:

```
SELECT *
from INT115_Payroll_Integration_Employment
WHERE (Employment_ExecutionId = 'Worker information-2019-03-06T02:49:49-4526155B07EC4FFD9A01DB540C9259C1' 
OR EmploymentDetail_ExecutionID = 'Worker information-2019-03-06T02:49:49-4526155B07EC4FFD9A01DB540C9259C1' 
OR EmploymentTerm_ExecutionID = 'Worker information-2019-03-06T02:49:49-4526155B07EC4FFD9A01DB540C9259C1' 
OR EmploymentComp_ExecutionID = 'Worker information-2019-03-06T02:49:49-4526155B07EC4FFD9A01DB540C9259C1')
AND Worker_Type = '1'
ORDER BY PERSONNELNUMBER ASC, SYNCSTARTDATETIME DESC, Employment_EndDate DESC, Employment_StartDate DESC
```

[image: Result select]

Now I want to get the first rows of each instance of unique PERSONNELNUMBER + EmploymentDetail_RecId from the above result.

I have accomplished to do this on all rows in the view after some inspiration from similar questions on here, but not on the rows from the first select.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
         SELECT *
                , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.EmploymentDetail_RecId ORDER BY e.PERSONNELNUMBER ASC, EmploymentDetail_RecId ASC, e.SYNCSTARTDATETIME DESC, e.Employment_EndDate DESC, e.Employment_StartDate DESC)
         FROM   INT115_Payroll_Integration_Employment e
       ) e
WHERE 
rn = 1
ORDER BY PERSONNELNUMBER ASC,  EmploymentDetail_RecId ASC, SYNCSTARTDATETIME DESC, Employment_EndDate DESC, Employment_StartDate DESC
```

[image: Select over partition]

How do I combine the two queries into one so that it only returns the two rows I want?

**UPDATE**

It was as simple as adding the WHERE clause of the first query in the sub-query of the second query as LukStorms suggested. Thanks.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
         SELECT *
                , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.EmploymentDetail_RecId ORDER BY e.PERSONNELNUMBER ASC, EmploymentDetail_RecId ASC, e.SYNCSTARTDATETIME DESC, e.Employment_EndDate DESC, e.Employment_StartDate DESC)
         FROM   INT115_Payroll_Integration_Employment e
         WHERE (Employment_ExecutionId = 'Worker information-2019-03-06T02:49:49-4526155B07EC4FFD9A01DB540C9259C1' 
         OR EmploymentDetail_ExecutionID = 'Worker information-2019-03-06T02:49:49-4526155B07EC4FFD9A01DB540C9259C1' 
         OR EmploymentTerm_ExecutionID = 'Worker information-2019-03-06T02:49:49-4526155B07EC4FFD9A01DB540C9259C1' 
         OR EmploymentComp_ExecutionID = 'Worker information-2019-03-06T02:49:49-4526155B07EC4FFD9A01DB540C9259C1')
         AND Worker_Type = '1'
       ) e
WHERE 
rn = 1
ORDER BY PERSONNELNUMBER ASC,  EmploymentDetail_RecId ASC, SYNCSTARTDATETIME DESC, Employment_EndDate DESC, Employment_StartDate DESC
```

Comment: Isn't it as simply as putting the whole WHERE clause of the first query in the sub-query of the second query?

Comment: I really thought I had tried that. Now i feel really stupid.